# Azure Mobile App - Getting 405 (Method Not Allowed) when trying POST

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to migrate my Azure Mobile Service .NET backend to an Azure Mobile App.

I was using some custom Web Api controllers, and after migration I'm getting a **`405 (Method Not Allowed)`** / `The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'.` error when trying to POST to a controller method that worked before.

I spent hours trying diffent CORS settings but I had no success so far.

This is how I currently configure Web Api:

```
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

new MobileAppConfiguration()
    .UseDefaultConfiguration()
    .ApplyTo(config);

var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*","*");
//var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*","GET,POST,DELETE,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,OPTIONS");
config.EnableCors(cors);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Rest",
    routeTemplate: "rest/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

The controller looks like that:

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefixAttribute("rest/companies")]
public class CompaniesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("my-active")]
    //[EnableCors("*","*","*")]
    public HttpResponseMessage SetActive(/*[FromBody]*/Company company)
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

What I tried too:

- Set CORS settings in web.config (custom headers / different settings), eg. `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,DELETE,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,OPTIONS" />`
- Added a cors message handler according this blog post
  (http://blog.bittercoder.com/2012/09/09/cors-and-webapi/)
- This handler is also removed: `<remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />`

One thing I noticed is, that a Azure Mobile App component seems to override   the allowed methods and allowed headers that I configured using `config.EnableCors(cors)`. I was only able to control all settings using web.config and the message handler. But it did not solve the 405 problem anyway.

At this point, I'm not sure if it's a CORS problem at all.

Any ideas? It's currently hard to find good documentation on Mobile Apps and I would appreciate if the .NET backend part would be open sourced... It's somewhat of a black box for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG, I found the problem with my code. I had to swap this two statements:

```
// Needs to be called before MapHttpRoute
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Rest",
    routeTemplate: "rest/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

As I was using Azure Mobile Services, calling `MapHttpAttributeRoutes` caused an error 'An item with the same key has already been added', so I removed that line. I had to re-insert it for Azure Mobile Apps again in order to get attribute routing to work, but I did it at the wrong place, so be careful.

Answer (score 3):

It could happen when you activate App Service Authorization and forget to change your mobile client url from http to https.
If so, your http Post will be redirected to the https url but with a Get message.
Found it thanks to Fiddler.

Answer (score 1):

If http Post is redirected to the https url as Get, try calling https directly.

Azure logs looks as follows in this case:

```
Received request: POST http://xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/Data/test
Information Redirecting: https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/Data/test
Received request: GET https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/Data/test
```

in this case call **https**://xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/Data/test