# Azure App Service Error 405 - The request could not be completed. (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: azure, xamarin.ios, azure-web-app-service

I'm working with Azure App Service .NET backend with a Xamarin.iOS app. I am able to successfully register a new user and I can see the user's details in the database. I have a custom ApiController, which handles the registration and the I'm able to save the details with a successful POST call.

However, when I try to log into the app, I get the following error:

```
{Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: The request could not be completed.  (Method Not Allowed)
```

Below is my code:

**The RegistrationController in the backend which successfully makes a POST call**

```
[MobileAppController]
[RoutePrefix("api/register")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public class RegisterController : ApiController
{

     [HttpPost]
    [Route("newuser")]
    public HttpResponseMessage NewUser(RegistrationRequest request)
    {
        // Registration code in here

    }

}
```

This is how I call this function on the client side:

```
public async Task<Result<UserProfile>> RegisterUser(RegistrationWrapper registrationrequest)
    {
        try
        {
            var registrationRequest = new JObject();
            registrationRequest.Add("username", registrationrequest.username);
            registrationRequest.Add("password", registrationrequest.password);
            registrationRequest.Add("email", registrationrequest.email);
            registrationRequest.Add("phone", registrationrequest.phone);
            registrationRequest.Add("firstname", registrationrequest.firstname);
            registrationRequest.Add("lastname", registrationrequest.lastname);

            var result = await client.InvokeApiAsync("register/newuser", registrationRequest);


     // Handle result here

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Result<UserProfile>.Failure(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace + ex.InnerException);
        }

    }
```

**Custom AuthController which handles the login**

This POST call fails with the error described above.

```
 [MobileAppController]
[RoutePrefix("api/auth")]
public class AuthController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(AuthenticationRequest credentials)
    {
        try
        {
              //Authentication code goes here

          catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ërror :" + e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new
            {
                Stacktrace = e.StackTrace,
                ErrorMessage = e.Message,
                Credentials = credentials
            });
        }


    }
```

How I invoke this function from the client side

```
 async Task<Result<Account>> Login(string username, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            var credentials = new JObject();
            credentials.Add("username", username);
            credentials.Add("password", password);
            var result = await client.InvokeApiAsync("auth", credentials);


          //Handle result here

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Result<Account>.Failure(ex, ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
        }

    }

}
```

I'm not sure why it's failing during the log in. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

After trying tons of solutions found here on StackOverflow, the one that finally worked for me was this first answer found on a similar   [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31630461/azure-mobile-app-getting-405-method-not-allowed-when-trying-post/31635227).

It seems that the **http** POST call is redirected to **https**.

After enabling authentication on your App Service in the Azure portal, you need to change the url to https.

So I changed mine from this:

```
http//{my_site}.azurewebsites.net
```

To this:

```
https//{my_site}.azurewebsites.net
```

On the client side, and now used this new one to create my local sync tables.
Everything works as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP status code 405 is returned when an API endpoint is called with a wrong (Not Allowed) HTTP method. For example, if instead of a POST request the endpoint is called with a GET request.